# How do I find out on which partition is my Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I have fully functional Windows and Ubuntu that is broken (I accidentally broke it) and want to reinstall Ubuntu. With Live-CD, I can see:

- 3 NTFS partitions,
- one ext4 and
- one unknown.

How do I find out which partitions belong to Windows? I thought that I might delete everything that wasn't NTFS, but I was afraid. Now I am using the **Install Ubuntu alongside [existing systems]...** option, but I guess that this will leave my broken Ubuntu untouched. So, again, I need to know which partitions to merge (perhaps add partitions of broken Ubuntu to new Ubuntu?).

Please, how can I learn how my system is divided? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The _3 NTFS_ partitions belongs to Windows. The _ext4_ partition is a Linux partition, so it belongs to Ubuntu, if you have no other Linux system installed. You could use the _ext4_ partition to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: And what about that unknown partision? How do I get to know what it is?

Comment: What is the size of the unknown **partition**? Could you make a screenshot and edit your question including the screenshot?

Comment: If you have used bitlocker in windows to lock(encrypt) any drive (partition) then that will be showed as unknown.

Comment: Leave the unknown partition alone. If it's not broken, don't try to fix it. There is not doubt that the `ext4` partition belongs to Linux, and the `NTFS` partitions belong to Windows. Deleting the `ext4` partition should not affect any of the other partitions, the unknown partition included. If you're getting this information from the LiveCD install set up, try using the 'Try' option and install GParted to take a closer look at your partitions.

Comment: the unknown partition could be your backup/restore partition for windows incase you need to revert to the factory settings. I could be wrong, but that is what I am thinking at this time.

Answer (score 1):

[This comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262611/how-do-i-find-out-on-which-partition-is-my-windows#comment347370_262611) by [Mochan](https://askubuntu.com/users/78161/mochan) seems to answer the question:

> Leave the unknown partition alone. If it's not broken, don't try to fix it. There is no doubt that the ext4 partition belongs to Linux, and the NTFS partitions belong to Windows. Deleting the ext4 partition should not affect any of the other partitions, the unknown partition included. If you're getting this information from the LiveCD install set up, try using the 'Try' option and install GParted to take a closer look at your partitions.